# Tkinter python filedialog.askopenfilename

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I'm not sure what im doing wrong in my code (below). I'm trying to get a function that would run and also return the result in a variable y. The idea is to have the user click on the select file button which would open the dialog box then once the user selected a file, save the file path to the variable y so that i can use it elsewhere in my code

Any help would be appreicated

```
from tkinter import Tk, Button, filedialog, Label
root = Tk()

root.title("test")
# Create a button with a custom callback
def openfiledialog():
 global y
 y = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir = "/",title = "Select f . 
 ile",filetypes = (("text file","*.txt"),("all files","*.*")))
 return y

print(y)

file_button = Button(root, text='Select File', command=openfiledialog)
file_button.pack()

exit_button = Button(root, text='Exit Program', command=root.destroy)
exit_button.pack()
w = Label(root, text='\n'"Step 1: Make sure the URL's in file are 
properly formatted, one URL per line"'\n''\n'
                  "Step 2: Select file"'\n''\n'
                 "Step 3: click run")
w.pack()


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: This looks like it should work just fine. However, your `print(y)` is going to run before the user ever has a chance to do anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to return a value when you are directly assigning the value to a global variable.

I also think the way you have written your Label is unorthodox. What you want to do can be done with one set of quotes.

When I have a known global variable I define it first before anything.

Your `print(y)` statement does not work as you think it does. It is only being run one time at the start of your program and at the moment it runs `y` is not equal to anything.

You need to move the print statement into the function.

Update: I have added a button to help with your below comment.
This button will print the current stored value of `y`.

The below code is a rework of your code.

```
from tkinter import Tk, Button, filedialog, Label


root = Tk()
y = ""
root.title("test")

def openfiledialog():
    global y
    y = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir = "/",title = "Select file",filetypes = (("text file","*.txt"),("all files","*.*")))

def check_path():
    global y
    print(y)

file_button = Button(root, text='Select File', command=openfiledialog)
file_button.pack()

exit_button = Button(root, text='Exit Program', command=root.destroy)
exit_button.pack()
w = Label(root, text="\nStep 1: Make sure the URL's in file are properly formatted, one URL per line\n\nStep 2: Select file\n\nStep 3: click run")
w.pack()

Button(root, text="Print current saved path", command = check_path).pack()


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks Mike! The reason i was printing y was so that i am able to use it after and outside of the function. What i would like to do is print(y) right before the main loop so i can get the file path, store the filepath in the variable and use it somewhere else in my code. Any chance you can help ? thanks in advance

Comment: @K.ahmed104 I think you are misunderstanding the use of print. The file path in my code is being stored and you can use it elsewhere. Print has nothing to do with storing the value.

Comment: @K.ahmed104 I have added a button to the code that will print the current stored value of `y` to the console. Let me know if you have any questions.